# Bases in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

> There's a theorem that states that having Hilbert space $H$, orthonormal basis $\{x_n\}$, and a set of  linearly independent unit vectors $\{y_n\}$, such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n - y_n\|^2<\infty$, implies that $\{y_n\}$ is also a basis. Suppose we have normalized $\{y_n\}$ such that $\langle x_n, y_n \rangle$ is real. Denote $\cos{\theta_n}:=\langle x_n, y_n \rangle$, $\theta \in [0, \pi)$. Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\theta_n|^2<\infty$.

I can show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|\theta_n|^2 < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5(1 - \cos{\theta_n})=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5(1 - \langle x_n, y_n \rangle)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5(\langle x_n, x_n \rangle - \langle x_n, y_n \rangle)$ $=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5\langle x_n, x_n - y_n \rangle$. I don't know how to show the last thing is finite though. Cauchy-Shwartz inequality seems useless and I don't see other nice inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, how'd you get the first part?

Once you have what you do, since this problem is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, you also have that the sum you care about is less than $\sum 5\langle y_n,y_n - x_n\rangle = \sum 5\langle-y_n,x_n-y_n\rangle$. If you add that to the other upper bound, I think you're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's right. What do you mean by "first part"? The first theorem is stated on the page 251 of "Functional analysis" by Lax. The inequality $\cos{x}\leq 1 - 0.2x^2$ for $|x|\leq \pi$ can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFAQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-math.ucdenver.edu%2F~spayne%2Fclassnotes%2Ftrigo.pdf&ei=QxNfU_4Ws8qxBIHagPAN&usg=AFQjCNHuBmrknK3vbOwNQjA6_aRYKkR37A&bvm=bv.65397613,d.cWc&cad=rja), lemma 1.3.5

Comment: The first part was that inequality. It's neat. I hadn't known that. It's kind of too bad that I hadn't. I bet that was something every mathematician knew a hundred years ago, you know.